# Write a particular PCollection to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Suppose I create two output PCollections as a result of SideOutputs and depending on some condition I want to write only one of them to BigQuery. How to do this?

Basically my use case is that I'm trying to make Write_Append and Write_Truncate dynamic. I fetch the information(append/truncate) from a config table that I maintain in BigQuery. So depending on what I have in the config table I must apply Truncate or Append.

So using SideOutputs I was able to create two PCollections(Append and Truncate respectively) out of which one will be empty. And the one which has all the rows must be written to BigQuery. Is this approach correct?

The code that i'm using:

```
 final TupleTag<TableRow> truncate =
                  new TupleTag<TableRow>(){};
              // Output that contains word lengths.
              final TupleTag<TableRow> append =
                  new TupleTag<TableRow>(){};

              PCollectionTuple results = read.apply("convert to table row",ParDo.of(new DoFn<String,TableRow>(){
              @ProcessElement
              public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
              {
                  String value = c.sideInput(configView).get(0).toString();
                  LOG.info("config: "+value);
                  if(value.equals("truncate")){
                      LOG.info("outputting to truncate");
                      c.output(new TableRow().set("color", c.element()));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      LOG.info("outputting to append");
                      c.output(append,new TableRow().set("color", c.element()));
                  }
                  //c.output(new TableRow().set("color", c.element()));
              }
          }).withSideInputs(configView).withOutputTags(truncate,
                  TupleTagList.of(append)));

              results.get(truncate).apply("truncate",BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .to("projectid:datasetid.tableid")
                        .withSchema(schema)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));

              results.get(append).apply("append",BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                        .to("projectid:datasetid.tableid")
                        .withSchema(schema)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED));
```

I need to perform one out of the two. If I do both table is going to get truncated anyways.

P.S. I'm using Java SDK (Apache Beam 2.1)

Comment: Is this a general question "whether this approach is correct?" or do you want some code solution?

Comment: @Marcin Zablocki Well both...I'd also like to have some code solution

Comment: You said that you have two PCollections, so what is the problem then? The approach of splitting and writing seems OK.

Comment: @MarcinZablocki Yes but I want to write one of them only. If I write both and in case I just want to append, truncate will also happen even if its corresponding PCollection has 0 rows/elements.

Comment: But you said one will be empty. So, why can't you just leave it as it is? If it's empty nothing will get written.

Comment: yes correct but the table will get truncated anyhow. I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: Please share your code, in particular the logic you are using for directing the output in the SideOutputs. One idea that comes to mind without seeing your code, is to write them to temp tables, then after you pipeline is finished drop into the BigQuery API and work out what you need to do then.

Comment: Hi @GrahamPolley I've updated my post with the code that I'm using. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right that, if your pipeline includes *at all* a write to a BigQuery table with WRITE_TRUNCATE, currently the table will get truncated even if there's no data. Feel free to [file a JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM) to support more configurable behavior in this case.

So if you want it to conditionally not get truncated, you need to conditionally not include that write transform at all. Is there a way to push the condition to that level, or does the condition actually have to be computed from other data in the pipeline?

(the only workaround I can think of is to use DynamicDestinations to dynamically choose the name of the table to truncate, and truncate some other dummy empty table instead - I can elaborate on this more after your answer to the previous paragraph)

Comment: Hi @jkff...a way to push the condition to that level is something I'm expecting as a solution to find here...and yes it must be computed from data that i retrieve from the config table that says either APPEND or TRUNCATE...so if there's a workaround using DynamicDestinations I'd really love to know that...

Comment: Can you, in your main program, say if (condition) { p.apply(...APPEND...) } else { p.apply(...TRUNCATE...) } ? Or does the condition itself depend on data computed by the pipeline and can not be evaluated by your main program that constructs the pipeline?

Comment: it depends on data computed by pipeline